# Xcode 6 beta 4 error for EXC__BAD_ACCESS when access PFObject nsmutablearray

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I am having the EXC_Bad_ACCESS error when i download the latest Xcode 6 beta4. my code was running fine before, and it break at second line.

```
println("row :\(indexPath.row) data count: \(groupData.count)")
let post:PFObject = groupData[indexPath.row] as PFObject
```

The console outputs "row: 0 data count: 2" which looks fine. this is happening to all my view controllers. I am not sure what went wrong. Please guide me! thank you ahead!

The following is how I add PFObject to the NSMutableArray:

```
self.partiPosts.removeAllObjects()
        //username.text = username.text + user.username
        var relation = user.relationForKey("participate")
        relation.query().findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if !error {
                for object:PFObject! in objects as [PFObject]{
                    println(object["battleName"])
                    self.partiPosts.addObject(object)
                }
```

Comment: What type is groupData?

Comment: I declared it as the following: var partiPosts:NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. App runs fine in beta 3, but randomly BAD_ACCESSes on beta 4. I haven't been able to get to the bottom of it yet. It's a mixture of Swift and Obj-C.

Comment: Please let me know if you fixed this error. I really need this to be fixed.

Comment: I am thinking it's bc this is a background thread. but even i add dispatch on main queue, the data shows there is object in the array. But it still give bad_access error. anyone please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Product - Clean

Cleared up problems with the same error code for me.